# Can TFS2010 Build Agent build SSIS packages

Tags: build, build-automation, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have a mixed .NET build for the TFS 2010 build agent (& controller): the build machine has to build Biztalk 2010 projects (created in VS2010) and SSIS packages (created in VS2008/BIDS).

Is that possible together ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the build process it invokes is all configured through WWF. As part of this anything can potentially be called using the InvokeProcess activity type even if it is outside of MSBuild.